# Applying theme for KeyboardView

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to change default style of KeyboardView by applying theme with no success. My target SDK is 1.6 and Xperia X10. Can someone help?

**/res/vaules/style.xml:**

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:keyboardViewStyle">@style/aa</item>
</style>
<style name="aa" parent="android:Widget.KeyboardView">
  <item name="android:keyTextSize">50sp</item>
  <item name="android:keyTextColor">#FF123456</item>
  <item name="android:keyPreviewHeight">150dp</item>
  <item name="android:labelTextSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<application android:theme="@style/myTheme"
..
```

Strange thing is that when I apply the style manually in layout, it works.

Comment: Interesting, the code you have here definitely seems correct. Did you get this fixed four years ago lol? Did you confirm that `KeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` still worked at least?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't style KeyboardView like any other component, because keyboard definitions overcome KeyboardView defs. Some hints:

Don't bother with the text size: the component find the perfect size to fit perfectly inside keys.

To define key sizes and another attributes, do it on keyboard xml definitions. See [this guide](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)

Eventually, [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2497237) probably will help you too.